# How can I adjust the the size of the circle to dynamically adjust to the width and height of any iPhone?

Tags: ios, snapkit

I am using snap kit to set out constraints. The first image is what I'm trying to achieve with the code below. How can I set the constraints off the circle's width and height to be dynamic on any iPhone screen ?

```
 profileImage = UIImageView()
        profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
        profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightBlue.cgColor
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 130
        profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector((tappedImage)))
        profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(profileImage)
        profileImage.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(topMargin*2)
            make.width.height.equalTo(view.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.71)
       }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAKxk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV0zG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple points...

First, `71%` of the view width will probably be too big. Start around `50%` and adjust to your liking.

You are using `.cornerRadius = 130` but your imageView may not be that size (certainly not on different devices), so you want to set the corner radius to one-half the width of the image view (or height, doesn't matter since it will be a square 1:1 ratio).

You could wait until `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to find out the run-time size of the image view, but if your image view ends up as a subview of another view, it won't be set at that point either.

Much easier to create a very simple `UIImageView` subclass:

```
class ProfileImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width * 0.5
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Then your view controller looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var profileImage: ProfileImageView!
    
    // your top margin value
    let topMargin: CGFloat = 20
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        profileImage = ProfileImageView()

        if let img = UIImage(named: "sampleProfilePic") {
            profileImage.image = img
        }

        profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(profileImage)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // this should give the same layout as your "snap" constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // center horizontally
            profileImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            // your topMargin value * 2 from safe-area top
            profileImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: topMargin * 2.0),
            // width
            //  71% of width of safe-area is probably too wide
            //  try starting at 50%
            profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50),
            // 1:1 ratio (square)
            profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImage.widthAnchor),
        ])

        //      profileImage.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        //          make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        //          make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(topMargin*2)
        //          make.width.height.equalTo(view.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.71)
        //      }

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector((tappedImage)))
        profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

}
```

Whenever the size of your `profileImage` view changes, the `ProfileImageView` class' `layoutSubviews()` will automatically set the corner radius appropriately.

Comment: Thanks but how would I set the constraints using snap kit ?

Comment: @RetroBoomin - sorry, I could have made that clearer in the code comments... I don't have snap-kit installed, so I posted the constraints I used. If you comment those out and use your snap constraints, it *should* give you the layout you want. Just note that 71% of the width may be too big, so try starting with `make.width.height.equalTo(view.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.50)` and adjust to your liking.

Comment: Thank you so much!!